# How is this an ascending sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

When my textbook was proving this lemma...

> Under the assumptions of Egoroff's Theorem, for each $\eta>0$ and $\delta>0$, there is a measurable subset A of E and an index N for which $|f_n - f| < \eta$ on A for all $n \geq N$ and $m(E \sim A) < \delta$.

The textbook says that "$|f_k - f|$ is properly defined, sicne f is real-valued, and it is measurable, so that the set $\{x \in E |f(x) - f_k(x)| < \eta\}$ is measurable." And then it says that this is also measurable, $E_n = \{x \in E | |f(x)-f_k(x)|< \eta \text{for all} k \geq n \}$, since "The intersection of a countable collection of measurable sets is measurable." But then it says that the sequence $\{E_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is an ascending collection of measurable sets. This is what I'm confused about...how is it ascending? We know that as n increases, the difference between f(x) and $f_k(x)$ decreases...so isn't it supposed to be a descending sequence?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $x\in\mathbb E_n$, then $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for all $k\geq n$. Hence $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for all $k\geq n+1$. Namely, $x\in \mathbb E_{n+1}$, and so ${\mathbb E_n}$ is ascending.

Comment: @awllower You can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying that a sequence of sets ${\mathbb E_n}$is ascending means that $\mathbb E_n\subset \mathbb E_{n+1}$.
Now, if $x\in \mathbb E_n$, then $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for all $k\geq n$. Hence $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for all $k\geq {n+1}$, namely, $x\in \mathbb E_{n+1}$. So the sequence is indeed ascending.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a bit confused about something else. The textbook says that $E_n = \{x \in E | |f(x)-f_k(x)|< \eta \text{for all} k \geq n \}$ is the intersection of $\{x \in E |f(x) - f_k(x)| < \eta\}$, right? We know that $\{x \in E |f(x) - f_k(x)| < \eta\}$ gets larger as k gets larger, right? Because we know that $f_n$ converges to $f$...so quicker as n gets larger. So the intersection of $\{x \in E |f(x) - f_k(x)| < \eta\}$ (for all possible k), should be k=1, right? THen how is $E_n = \{x \in E | |f(x)-f_k(x)|< \eta \text{for all} k \geq n \}$ the intersection?

Comment: Let me simplify the notation by denoting the set {${x\in E\mid |f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta}$} by $D_k$. I am confused why you know that $D_k$ gets larger as $k$ gets larger? Are there other assumptions on the sequence $f_k$? Or how could you conclude that $D_k$ ascends when $k$ increases? I think just the fact that $f_k$ converges to $f$ suffices not for this purpose. Also the intersection property in question is just another set-theoretic consequence, not particularly involved with the situation here. Hope this helps.