# How is this set ascending?

Tags: real-analysis

In Royden's analysis, the proof for Lemma 10 in chapter 3 states the following:

For each $k$, the function $|f - f_k |$ is properly defined, since $f$ is real-valued, and it is measurable, so that the set $\{ x \in E : |f(x) - f_k(x)| < \eta\}$ is measurable. The intersection of a countable collection of measurable sets is measurable. Therefore $$E_n = \{ x \in E : |f(x) - f_k(x)| < \eta \text{ for all } k \geq n \}$$ is a measurable set. Then $\{E_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an ascending collection of measurable sets.

It seems like such a set would be descending. Is this an error in the text, or am I missing something?

Comment: Note: I think there should be tags for classic textbook authors, like Royden, Rudin, Dummit and Foote, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305412/how-is-this-an-ascending-sequence

Comment: @user1876508: no, there should not. A user should instead include the precise information on the textbook when a question is about a textbook. You should specify at the very least the author (Royden in your case), the full title (which would be "Real Analysis"), and also the edition (since if there are typos, they could easily have been fixed with updated printings). A complete bibliographic information is much more useful than just an author name, especially in the case where an author can write many well-received textbooks (e.g. Rudin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you increase $n$, you make it easier for a point $x$ to be in $E_n$, so the sets $E_n$ are non-decreasing. For example, in order for $x$ to be in $E_2$, $x$ must satisfy $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for $k=2,3,4,\ldots$. In order for $x$ to be in $E_3$, however, $x$ need only satisfy the inequality for $k=3,4,5,\ldots$; it no longer has to satisfy $|f(x)-f_2(x)|<\eta$. More generally, if $m<n$, and $x\in E_m$, then $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for all $k\ge m$ and therefore automatically for all $k\ge n>m$, so $x\in E_n$, and $E_m\subseteq E_n$. However, if there is a point $x\in E$ that satisfies $|f(x)-f_k(x)|<\eta$ for every $k\ge n$ but **not** for $k=m$, then $x\in E_n\setminus E_m$.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You’re welcome.

Comment: BRIAN: YOU ARE ALMOST 200 K !!! HOW DOES IT FEEL TO BE ALMOST 200K IF YOU DONT MIND ME ASKING YOU.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: I try not to get caught up in the numbers too much, but I do see them as an indication that I’ve provided a lot of useful help, so I’m pleased.